# Regex pattern to extract tag and its contents

Tags: python, regex

considering this:

```
input = """Yesterday<person>Peter</person>drove to<location>New York</location>"""
```

how can one use regex patterns to extract:

```
person: Peter
location: New York
```

This works well, but I dont want to hard code the tags, they can change:

```
print re.findall("<person>(.*?)</person>", input)
print re.findall("<location>(.*?)</location>", input)
```

Comment: You are getting dangerously close to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: @DevEx please see the modification in the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a tool designed for the work.  I happen to like lxml but their are other

```
>>> minput = """Yesterday<person>Peter Smith</person>drove to<location>New York</location>"""
>>> from lxml import html
>>> tree = html.fromstring(minput)
>>> for e in tree.iter():
        print e, e.tag, e.text_content()
        if e.tag() == 'person':          # getting the last name per comment
           last = e.text_content().split()[-1]
           print last


<Element p at 0x3118ca8> p YesterdayPeter Smithdrove toNew York
<Element person at 0x3118b48> person Peter Smith
Smith                                            # here is the last name
<Element location at 0x3118ba0> location New York
```

If you are new to Python then you might want to visit this [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) to get an installer for a number of packages including LXML.

Comment: Thanks @PyNEwbie in case of ´<person>Peter Smith</person>´ how can I use ´text_content()´ to extract only ´Smith´ ?

Comment: You can't but you can split the string once you have it.

Comment: @PyNEwbie, is there any similar method I can use to get words that are not inside the tags: `"Yesterday" & "drove to"` ?

Comment: Precisely, I want to do something like: Yesterday _person_ Smith drove to _location_ New York. Thanks @PyNEwbie for helping with lxml to parse the trees

Answer (score 3):

Avoid parsing HTML with regex, use an HTML parser instead.

Here's an example using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

data = "Yesterday<person>Peter</person>drove to<location>New York</location>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

print 'person: %s' % soup.person.text
print 'location: %s' % soup.location.text
```

prints:

```
person: Peter
location: New York
```

Note the simplicity of the code.

Hope that helps.